# Connecting to MySql gear on another gear

Tags: mysql, openshift

so I have two free gears on OpenShift.
One is a PHP with MySql 5.7 from:
https://github.com/icflorescu/openshift-cartridge-mysql
To which I can remote login from my PC without any problem by SSH tunnel.
Now on the second gear I wanted to create Spring Boot app that would connect to DB on the first gear. Using `env | grep MYSQL` on first gear I receive:
`OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT=13306`
`OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST=127.10.104.130`

So this + my logging data was put into Spring `application.properties`, after successfull build Spring crashed at data pool creation because it could not connect to database so I SSHed into second hear and tried accessing MySQL instance from first gear via:
`mysql -u root -h 127.10.104.130 -P 13306` but I get error message:
`Can not connect to MySQL Server on '127.10.104.130' (113)`
After that I tried:
`mysql -u root -h myAppName-domain.rhcloud.com -P 13306` which results in longer time of connection but ultimatelly failling with:
`Can not connect to MySQL Server on 'myAppName-domain.rhcloud.com' (110)`
And I can easly ping gear#1 from gear#2 so I am confused - do I need some extra sql config or firewall settings? I am also doing tail on mysql logs and nothing is showing up like connection is not even made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are connecting on another gear you have to use the `OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PROXY_PORT` instead.

The easiest way I find to tell if its a database issue or a network issue is to simply try to telnet to the remote mysql host.

Ex - this should result in a connection timeout if you are on a different gear.

```
telnet 127.10.104.130 13306
```

But this should connect:

```
telnet <mysql app id>.domain.rhcloud.com <WHATEVER THE PROXY PORT IS>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  I neeeded to tear up old instance and create new one as scalable in order to get ```OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PROXY_PORT``` variable set properly. After that I was able to connect from different instance.   Thank You guys very much @Ionut-Cristian Florescu for great cartridge and @ChuchMac for great answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of the [openshift-cartridge-mysql](https://github.com/icflorescu/openshift-cartridge-mysql) mentioned above.

It's been a while since I've published that cartridge, but if I remember correctly, the setup script is quite unassuming and there's nothing created by default, so you have to create your own users, databases and **explicitly grant the appropriate privileges**.

Connect from your PC either by `ssh` or by Workbench over ssh tunnel, create your user and database, then execute something like:

```
GRANT ... ; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

You can learn more on MySQL's GRANT command [in the official manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html).

There's a line in the repo [README](https://github.com/icflorescu/openshift-cartridge-mysql/blob/master/README.md) exemplifying how you could grant remote access to `root`, which is not as unsafe as it looks because you can only access the DB gear from your main application gear.

But ideally you'd want to limit the access as much as possible (to a specific user coming from a specific host/IP, such as your main application gear). Something like this:

```
GRANT ALL ON appdb.* TO 'appuser'@'appgear';
```

Don't forget to `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` when you're done.

I hope this helps,

[@icflorescu](https://github.com/icflorescu)